# RelativeLayout - Keep Fragment at the bottom

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-relativelayout

This is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonsFragment1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonsFragment1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/showSomething"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

    </ScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonsFragment2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scrollViewer" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The last FrameLayout contains a Fragment with some Buttons. This FrameLayout should be kept at the bottom of the screen. But with this code, the fragment `buttonsFragment2` is not displayed on my Smartphone.

I see only the `buttonsFragment1` on top, I can scroll down the LinearLayout but at the bottom, there is no `buttonsFragment2`. What is wrong?

EDIT: My Fragment class:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myFragment, container, false);

    Fragment topFrag = new TopFragment();
    Fragment bottomFrag = new BottomFragment();

    FragmentTransaction top = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    top.add(R.id.topFragment, topFragment).commit();

    FragmentTransaction bottom = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    bottom.add(R.id.bottomFragment, bottomFragment).commit();

    return view;
}
```

Comment: How are you loading the fragments? Are you using the FragmentManager in your Java code? Please show us this part of your code.

Comment: I've done that, but the display of both fragment works, also the bottom fragment. But only if the content of the ScrollView is not to long. If I have a big SrollView content and I have to scroll, the bottomFragment is not displayed.

Comment: Unrelated to your question: you can improve your code by using a single transaction. I don't know if this will solve your current problem, though.

Comment: To answer your question: I suggest using a `RelativeLayout` as your top-level container instead of the current `LinearLayout`. This will give you the flexibility you need for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I've changed it to a RelativeLayout (edited) but without any success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your layout correctly, this is the solution you are searching. The scrollview fills the screen between your fragments:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonsFragment1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonsFragment2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonsFragment1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/showSomething"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

    </ScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonsFragment2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: After adding the line         android:layout_above="@+id/buttonsFragment2"
... the content of the scrollView disappears

Comment: did you add match_parent to your ScrollView? Then you should show the layout of your fragments. probably the bottom one is having a match_parent in height. Hint: if you face this with Fragments, include your Fragment-Layout in one XML so that you can see it in the layout-UI

Comment: Yes I did. The bottom fragment height is a RelativeLayout with height = wrap_content and 1 button with a height of 50dp

Comment: There is something have not shown. This layout is perfectly fine in my layout-UI. Furthermore your code is definitely not the code you are having. The names of your layouts and your Fragment instances do not match.